# Refresh data continuously in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a project which is showing export/import numbers. However the numbers change continuously. Which is why I need a refresh button. I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var cli = new WebClient();
    cli.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    string response = cli.UploadString("Can't share company API and token sorry");

    var responseModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ihap>(response);

    IthalatGunluk.Text = responseModel.Import.ToString();
    IthalatAylik.Text = responseModel.ImportMonthly.ToString();
    IthalatYillik.Text = responseModel.ImportMonthlyPrevious.ToString();

    IhracatGunluk.Text = responseModel.Export.ToString();
    IhracatAylik.Text = responseModel.ExportMonthly.ToString();
    IhracatYillik.Text = responseModel.ExportMonthlyPrevious.ToString();

    Dolar.Text = responseModel.Dolar.ToString();
    Euro.Text = responseModel.Euro.ToString();
}


class Ihap
{
    public double Dolar { get; set; }
    public double Euro { get; set; }
    public int Import { get; set; }
    public int Export { get; set; }
    public int ImportMonthly { get; set; }
    public int ImportMonthlyPrevious { get; set; }
    public int ExportMonthly { get; set; }
    public int ExportMonthlyPrevious { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would a timer not be better ? why not use a timer instead of a button ? (https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-timer/)

Comment: Well, that's also a good idea. I'm thinking about to use a timer as well, but company asked me to put a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just move the code currently in your constructor to a separate method and then call it from both the constructor and the button click handler:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RefreshData();
}

public void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => RefreshData();

private void RefreshData()
{
    var cli = new WebClient();
    cli.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    string response = cli.UploadString("Can't share company API and token sorry");

    var responseModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Ihap>(response);

    IthalatGunluk.Text = responseModel.Import.ToString();
    IthalatAylik.Text = responseModel.ImportMonthly.ToString();
    IthalatYillik.Text = responseModel.ImportMonthlyPrevious.ToString();

    IhracatGunluk.Text = responseModel.Export.ToString();
    IhracatAylik.Text = responseModel.ExportMonthly.ToString();
    IhracatYillik.Text = responseModel.ExportMonthlyPrevious.ToString();

    Dolar.Text = responseModel.Dolar.ToString();
    Euro.Text = responseModel.Euro.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to refers the UI.

1. Use [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simplifying-mvvm-inotifypropertychanged-on-xamarin-forms/) to Update your import and export numbers. So it will update the UI when the value is changed.
2. Use [Threading timer](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/timer-class-in-threading-C-Sharp/) to load the new import and export number as you required time interval
3. Create ObservableCollection and put your import and export numbers, it will update the UI when the number is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the data by calling a web-service and binding properties of the API response.

So basically, your question is how to do that every X seconds.

You can use threading and timer (C# timer - not Xamarin.Timer) to make the API call periodically.

Like so:

```
public static Timer YourTimer;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    YourTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); //In milliseconds
    YourTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(RunThis);
    YourTimer.AutoReset = true;
    YourTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private static void RunThis(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Your API call here
}
```

> Note: you will need to use `System.Timers` namespace.

Hope it helps.